# Animating divs inside another div onClick and onMouseLeave

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, mouseleave

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I have a div (marked in black in image below), which contains 2 other div (marked in red and blue) - one has a single image and is shown and the other has 3 images and it's currently hidden.

[image]

When a user clicks the single image its parent div makes a slide up animation and becomes hidden and the second div shows.

[image]

When the user leaves the parent div area - it makes the slide down animation and returns to initial state (image 1).

I wrote this code to make the slide up animation:

```
$(".img_btn_info").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({'margin-top': '-30px'}, 500);
});
```

It worked just fine. But now I tried to write the code for the second part, when the mouse leaves, and it didn't work as I expected - it animated down the parent div instead of the first one.

```
$(".img_btn_info").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({'margin-top': '-30px'}, 500, function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({'margin-top': '30px'}, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

So how can I make this work correctly?

**UPDATE**

Here's a  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UsaD4/2/) of the code

Comment: jsfiddle will be appriciated

Comment: @SomnathKharat I updated my question with a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change this:

```
$(".img_btn_info").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({'margin-top': '-30px'}, 500, function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({'margin-top': '30px'}, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

to this:

```
    $(".img_btn_info").click(function(){
        var $here = $(this).parent();
        $here.animate({'margin-top': '-30px'}, 500, function(){
            $(this).parent().mouseleave(function(){
                $here.animate({'margin-top': '0'}, 500);
            });
         });
     });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UsaD4/3/)

Comment: I don't see the second animation, on .mouseleave

Comment: Is this the second animation: $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $here.animate({'margin-top': '0'}, 500);
        }); @Igal is in the answer, see jsfiddle please

Comment: OK, figured it out! Instead of `$(this).mouseleave` it should be `$this.parent().mouseleave` - here's the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/UsaD4/4/ Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: oh yes, you can modify it whatever you want, I have seen that works fine. Glad to help you @Igal

Answer (score 0):

I would call all the DOM elements directly instead of using .parent().parent(). etc.

E.g. something like:

```
$(".img_btn_info").click(function(){
    $('#second-box').animate({'margin-top': '-30px'}, 500, function(){
        $('#container').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#second-box').animate({'margin-top': '30px'}, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is I have a few of these divs with inner divs on my page, so I have to use .parent()